# How to update Fragment view from onActivityResult() in parent Activity

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, fragment

In my Activity, I do implement onActivityResult:

```
@Override
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            //do something

        }
```

I tried to implement onActivityResult in that Fragment:

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == 10020) {
            Log.e(TAG, "requestCode == 10020");
            tv1.setText(Html.fromHtml("You are currently on a <b>GOLD</b> plan. You can:"));
        }
        Log.e(TAG, "line 401");

    }
```

and BroadcastReceive, which will be called when reach onActivityResult in parent Activity but both of them is not work. How can I do that? Help me!

Comment: instead of modifying the fragment UI from Activity, tell your fragment to modify it like `fragment.setTv1(Html.fromHtml("You are currently on a <b>GOLD</b> plan. You can:"));`. In fragment implement this method, and do whatever you need.

Comment: pls read my question again, i missed an info about my case :D

Comment: show how you `startActivityForResult()`, and where you do that?

Comment: i use startIntentSenderForResult for google billing, and i want to update view after user bought product.

Comment: please show the code, and where you call it. it matters.

Comment: PendingIntent pendingIntent = buyIntentBundle.getParcelable("BUY_INTENT");
            startIntentSenderForResult(pendingIntent.getIntentSender(),
                    BILLING_RESULT_CODE,
                    new Intent(), Integer.valueOf(0), Integer.valueOf(0),
                    Integer.valueOf(0));

Comment: i call this command in parent activity

Comment: `in parent activity` then you will receive a result in parent activity as well

Answer (score 0):

In your fragment declare a public method that takes in all the required information to update the view (some text?).  When you're creating your fragment in the activity, keep a reference to it so you can call that method.

### Activity

```
MyFragment fragment;

oncreateView() {
    if(savedInstance == null) {
        fragment = // create fragment
        // getSupportFragmentManager() and add it to the activity 
    }
}

onActivityResult() {
    fragment.updateText(String text);
}
```

### Fragment

```
public class MyFragment {
    ...
    ...
    public void updateText(String text) {
        // update the textview with the new text
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried your solution, I can log method updateText successfully, but Fragment 's view is still not updated. am I missing anything? :(
((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv1_FragmentAccount)).setText(Html.fromHtml("You are currently on a <b>GOLD</b> plan. You can:"));

Comment: Not sure. Would you mind posting the relevant code in both the activity and fragment?